# I'd like to add the text on the Button using python KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

I make a project using python KIVY. I need you help

Q1. I'd like to add the text 'Select Mode' on the button. Like Picture:

[image]

Q2. I want to make a kv file, but I can't make it even if I look for a lot of information.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) #white
from kivy.lang import Builder

class AIObjectCameraApp(App): 
    def button_click_callback(self, instance): #Callback print
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=200) 
        button = Button(text='Object', size_hint=(.5, .0), font_size=50) 
        button.bind(on_press=self.button_click_callback) #Click Event
        button2 = Button(text='Street', size_hint=(.5, .0), font_size=50) 
        button2.bind(on_press=self.button_click_callback) #click Event
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(button2)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    AIObjectCameraApp().run()
```

Comment: use a label for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a label:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) #white
from kivy.lang import Builder

class AIObjectCameraApp(App): 
    def button_click_callback(self, instance): #Callback print
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=200) 
        lab=Label(text="Select Mode", font_size='35',color =[0, 0, 0, 1])
        button = Button(text='Object', size_hint=(.5, .0), font_size=50) 
        button.bind(on_press=self.button_click_callback) #Click Event
        button2 = Button(text='Street', size_hint=(.5, .0), font_size=50) 
        button2.bind(on_press=self.button_click_callback) #click Event
        layout.add_widget(lab)
        layout.add_widget(button)
        layout.add_widget(button2)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    AIObjectCameraApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks again. I try this code. Also add size_hint But The text was not printed.

Comment: @Puya you can have the size like you want to . I have added the color to text to make it visible. now try it

Comment: also use pos_hint

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your code that uses a `kv` string and includes your desired text:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) #white
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "Select Mode"
        color: 0,0,0,1  #default is white, which will not be visible
        size_hint: 1, .5
        font_size: 50
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 200
        Button:
            text: "Object"
            size_hint: .5, .0
            font_size: 50
            on_press: app.button_click_callback(self)
        Button:
            text: "Street"
            size_hint: .5, .0
            font_size: 50
            on_press: app.button_click_callback(self)

'''

class AIObjectCameraApp(App):
    def button_click_callback(self, instance): #Callback print
        print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AIObjectCameraApp().run()
```

Comment: This comment is also helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: hey john, this is me InfinityTM